# jquery waypoints and .scroll() conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

Here's my JS code:

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var height = $(window).height();
    var opacity = ((height - scrollTop) / height);
    var scale = ((height - (scrollTop/10)) / height);
    console.log(opacity);
    if(opacity>=0.05){
        $.each(links, function( i, link ) {
            $(link).css({
                'opacity': opacity,
             });
        })} else {
            $(link).css({
                'opacity': 0.05
            });
        }
    if(scale>=0.9){
         $('#index').css({
            'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'
         });
    } else {
        $('#index').css({
            'transform': 'scale(0.9)'
        });
    }
});
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#aboutContent').waypoint(function(direction) {
        alert('hit!'); 
    });
});
```

The .scroll() function works exactly as I want it but the waypoint doesn't at all. If however, I remove the .scroll() function the waypoint works as it should. Can anyone spot what could be causing the issue? I can't find any know conflicts between .scroll() and waypoints. Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zocdvefx/ If you remove the .scroll() function the waypoint should work.

Thanks!
Jamie

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshoot this type of issue by just looking at your code. Please move your relevant code into a jsfiddle or other environment where we can reproduce/see the issue.

Comment: Thought that might be the case. Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/zocdvefx/

If you remove the $(window).scroll() function the waypoint works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your fiddle the issue is in this `if-else` block:

```
if (opacity >= 0.05) {
  $.each(links, function(i, link) {
    $(link).css({
      'opacity': opacity,
    });    
  })
} else {
  $(link).css({ // <-- link is no longer in scope and is undefined 
    'opacity': 0.05
  });
}
```

Changing `link` to `links` in the line I highlighted above will resolve your issue.

For future reference always check your browser's developer console (usually F12) when you're running into an issue. As soon as I opened it in your jsfiddle it immediately started telling me what the issue was: `ReferenceError: link is not defined`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Lesson learnt (designer trying to develop over here!)